# Messed up Python packages installement? (OS X)

Tags: python, installation, dependencies, pip

I think i somehow messed up installing packages for python and the whole environment. Whenever i want to install something i run into problems like: 
`directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled`

Also PyCharm thinks i still need to install referenced packages (no modules. Which is wrong since i can use them. When i click on 'install referenced packages' i get the mentioned warning from above plus:
`OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted`


Hopefully one of you can help! :(

Best regards
Matthias

Edit: At some point i also installed a venv for python. Maybe this relates to my problem. I'm rly sorry i am new to it and have no idea what i'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue with your permissions, if you run

```
which python
```

you will see where your current version of python is installed. If you're on osx, I seriously recommend downloading brew here: https://brew.sh/. Just paste that command into your terminal, then you should install python by running:

```
brew install python
```

This will give you some later instructions, but the brew bundled version of python is alot more robust than the one that gets bundled with your system. Another note is that if you're using virtual environments, consider using virtualenvwrapper [here](http://exponential.io/blog/2015/02/10/install-virtualenv-and-virtualenvwrapper-on-mac-os-x/). This should make things run alot more smoothly for you :)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Also, it might be as easy as running chown and setting the ownership of your python distro to your own user name. But again, to avoid issues like this, I'd use brew to manage these things for me.

Comment: When i enter which python it returns <br>
`/usr/bin/python`

When i want to add chown to that path with my user i get: <br>
`chown: /usr/bin/python: Operation not permitted`

Comment: `sudo chown !!` You'd have to sudo because it currently doesn't belong to your user.

Comment: I did it with sudo :/ my active user is kajuken (id -un)

`sudo chown kajuken /usr/bin/python`
chown: /usr/bin/python: Operation not permitted

Comment: Yep in that case, I'd very seriously recommend moving to brew to run python.

Comment: can i clean it somehow?  `brew install python` brings nothing other than `Warning: python 2.7.13_1 is already installed`

Comment: As I was saying earlier, its best to install virtualenvwrapper, which (by default), will create a .virtualenvs folder in your home folder, which will allow you to deal with having multiple versions of python and pip on your system. That way you'll never have to deal with problems like these again :)